$\alpha$ is separable iff $F(\alpha)$ is and separability is transitive.
This is probably the hardest set of exercises from Allan Clark's book Elements of Abstract Algebra. I've recently revisited it and decided to write up the simplest possible solutions I could think of because everything that I find online uses some facts not yet reached in the text. I would ask someone to please proofread my answer and provide a simpler one if such exists. I will be solving the following exercises:

Show that an element $\alpha$ of an extension $E$ of a field $F$ of characteristic $p \neq 0$ is separable iff $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^p)$.


Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p \neq 0$ and $E$ a finite extension. Let $E^{(p)}$ be the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $\alpha^p$ for every $\alpha \in E$ and all the elements of $F$. Prove that $E$ is separable iff $E^{(p)} = E$.


Prove that $\alpha$ is separable iff the extension $F(\alpha)$ is.


Let $F$ be a field, $E$ a separable extension and $D$ a separable extension of $E$. Prove that $D$ is separable over $F$.


For the first exercise, if $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^p)$, then $\alpha = f(\alpha^p)$ for some polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ (because $\{1, \alpha^p, \dots, \alpha^{np}\}$ is a basis for some $n$). Then $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) := x - f(x^p)$, but clearly $g'(x) = 1$ so there are no double roots of this polynomial. So $\alpha$ is separable.
For the other direction, suppose $F(\alpha) \neq F(\alpha^p)$ (so $F(\alpha^p) \subset F(\alpha)$) and note that, then, the polynomial $f(x) := x^p - \alpha^p = (x - \alpha)^p$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F(\alpha^p)$. Truly, if there was some $g \neq f$ such that $g \mid f$, then $g$ would be of the form $g(x) = (x - \alpha)^k$ for some $k < p$. But after expanding $g$, we see that the coefficient next to $x^{k - 1}$ is $k\alpha$, but that's not in $F(\alpha^p)$ by assumption. So, $f$ is irreducible and minimal for $\alpha$. Now let $n = \left[ F(\alpha^p) : F \right]$ and note that $\left[ F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^p) \right] = p$ by what we just showed, so from $$\left[ F(\alpha) : F \right] = \left[ F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^p) \right] \left[ F(\alpha^p) : F \right]$$ we get that $\left[ F(\alpha) : F \right] = np$.
Now consider the minimal polynomial $g(x)$ for $\alpha^p$ over $F$. It is of degree $n$, so $g(x^p)$ is of degree $pn$ and $\alpha$ is a root of it, so it is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$. But clearly, $(g(x^p))' = 0$, so $\alpha$ is inseparable.
Now, for one direction of the second problem, suppose $E \neq E^{(p)}$ and pick $\alpha \in E \setminus E^{(p)}$. Then $F(\alpha) \neq F(\alpha)$ (otherwise $\alpha$ is clearly in $E^{(p)}$), so $\alpha$ is inseparable and so is $E$.
For the other direction, write $E = F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n)$ (because $E$ is finite) and note that $E^{(p)} = F(\alpha_1^p, \alpha_2^p, ..., \alpha_n^p)$. Truly, if $\alpha \in E$, then $\alpha = \sum_i c_i \alpha_i$, so $\alpha^p = \sum_i c_i^p \alpha_i^p \in E^{(p)}$ and everything should be clear from that. Now consider the case $n = 2$, some two $\beta \in E$ that we want to prove separable, some independent $\alpha \in E$ and note
$$\left[ F(\alpha, \beta) : F \right] = \left[ F(\alpha, \beta) : F(\alpha, \beta^p) \right]\left[ F(\alpha, \beta^p) : F(\alpha^p, \beta^p) \right]\left[ F(\alpha^p, \beta^p) : F \right],$$
so our assumption gives us that $F(\alpha, \beta) = F(\alpha, \beta^p)$ and $\beta = g_0(\alpha) + g_1(\alpha)\beta^p + \dots + g_n(\alpha)\beta^{np}$ for some $g_1, \dots, g_n \in F[x]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But this would contradict the linear independence of $\alpha, \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m$ unless each of the polynomials was independent of $\alpha$. And so we get that all of them are constants in $F$, so $F(\beta) = F(\beta^p)$. The case where more elements generate $E$ can be done by induction.
For the nontrivial direction of part 3, if $\alpha$ is separable, $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^p)$ and so every element can be represented as some linear combination of $p$-th powers, thus making the extension separable.
For part 4, take any $\alpha \in D$ and write $\alpha = c_0 + c_1\alpha^p + \dots + c_n\alpha^{np}$ for $c_0, \dots, c_n \in E$ which are separable over $F$. Then by considering the finite extension $F(c_0, \dots, c_n, \alpha)$ and making use of the fact that each $c_i$ is separable over $F$ we get
$$\alpha = \sum_{i = 0}^n \sum_j (k_{ij} c_i^{jp}) \alpha^{ip},$$
for some coefficients $k_{ij} \in F$. We've actually written $\alpha$ as a linear combination of $p$-th powers and as $\alpha$ was arbitrary, we have that $D$ is separable over $F$.
